# Failed to generate endpoints api with maven using Multiclass API - Java Inheritance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I based my endpoint classes from this [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/multiclass#using_java_inheritance)

```
@Api(name = "tictactoe", version = "v1")
class TicTacToeBase { … }

// TicTacToeA and TicTacToeB both behave as if they have the same @Api annotation as
// TicTacToeBase
class TicTacToeA extends TicTacToeBase { … }
class TicTacToeB extends TicTacToeBase { … }
```

Endpoints works perfectly with android studio's gradle.

but when I move the source files to my maven-structured project it doesn't recognized `TicTacToeA`  & `TicTacToeB` as endpoints classes. I've tried to use just simple annotated Endpoint class and it works.

web.xml contents from gradle-structured project is also copied to maven-structured project.

I noticed from **target** folder of maven-structured project that web.xml was **generated** but this time only with
`<param-value>com.sample.TicTacToeBase</param-value>`
shouldn't it be

`<param-value>com.sample.TicTacToeA,com.sample.TicTacToeB</param-value>`?

Answer (score 0):

You are right! Each API needs to be declared in the *web.xml* file. Normally you can do this in the file **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**. (the *web.xml* file in the *target* folder is just a copy)

For example, you have a class *TicTacToeAPI* with annotations which define your API and two subclasses which extend this one.

#### TicTacToeAPI

```java
@Api(name = "tictactoe",
    canonicalName = "TicTacToe API",
    version = "v1",
    title = "TicTacToe Client API",
    description = "TicTacToe Client API.",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
            ownerName = "tictactoe.com",
            ownerDomain = "tictactoe.com")
)
public class TicTacToeAPI {
    // ...
}
```

#### TicTacToeA & TicTacToeB

```java
public class TicTacToeA extends TicTacToeAPI {
    // Exposes some methods using annotations.
}

public class TicTacToeB extends TicTacToeAPI {
    // Exposes some methods using annotations.
}
```

In your *web.xml* file, you cannot declare only the top level class. **All subclasses have to be defined**.

#### web.xml

```xml
<web-app>
    ...

    <!--Google Cloud Endpoint-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.sample.TicTacToeA,
                com.sample.TicTacToeB
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    ...
</web-app>
```

Comment: Yep, had tried it. This works on *not* maven-structured project. For the meantime, I just annotated each subclass not a good practice for maintainability but a workaround as of now.